# Re imageviewer issue

Tags: java, codenameone

The images from json are displayed in grid view as expected but when i click them only 2 images can be swiped through image viewer. I dont need to upload the images as in photoshare demo I just have to display all images in a gridview and then show them in imageviewer when clicked. I am having hard time to accomplish this. Below is the what I have done so far.

**ImageGallery form**

```
@Override
protected void beforeImgGallery(Form f) {
    int iter = 0;
    GridLayout gr = new GridLayout(1, 2);
    Container grid = new Container(gr);
    GridLayout gr = new GridLayout(1, 2);
    grid.setScrollableY(true);
    grid.addComponent(new InfiniteProgress());
    f.addComponent(grid);
    createPictureCommand(grid);
}
```

**connectionRequest** - here i dont need to update the image in server:

```
private static boolean animating;
private Vector<Map<String, Object>> responsesgallery;
String[] galleryPhotoUrlCopy = new String[100];
int galleryIndex;

private void createPictureCommand(final Container grid) {
    ConnectionRequest mp = new ConnectionRequest() {
        private long key;

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
            results = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
            responsesgallery = (Vector<Map<String, Object>>) results.get("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < responsesgallery.size(); i++) {
                Hashtable hm = (Hashtable) responsesgallery.get(i);
                String galleryImgId = (String) hm.get("news_id");

                String galleryPhotoUrl = (String) hm.get("photo");
                galleryPhotoUrlCopy[i] = galleryPhotoUrl;
                galleryIndex = i;
                key = (long) i;
                long[] img = {key};
                //problem lies in here
                imageList = new ImageList(img);

                final Button btn = createImageButton(key, grid, i, galleryPhotoUrl);
                imageList.addImageId(key);
                grid.addComponent(i, btn);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {
        }
    };
    mp.setUrl(SERVER_URL);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(mp);
}

Command createBackCommand(final Container viewerParent, final Container grid) {
    return new Command("Back") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            viewerParent.getParent().replace(viewerParent, grid, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, true, 300));
            Form frm = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
            frm.removeAllCommands();
            frm.setBackCommand(null);
        }
    };
}
```

**imagelist class**

```
public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://capitaleyedevelopment.com/~admin/traffic/api/news/getLatestNews";
private static String THUMB_URL_PREFIX = SERVER_URL + "image?";

class ImageList implements ListModel<Image> {

    private int selection;
    private long[] imageIds;
    private EncodedImage[] images;
    private EventDispatcher listeners = new EventDispatcher();

    public void addImageId(long id) {
        long[] n = new long[imageIds.length + 1];
        EncodedImage[] nImages = new EncodedImage[n.length];
        System.arraycopy(imageIds, 0, n, 0, imageIds.length);
        System.arraycopy(images, 0, nImages, 0, images.length);
        n[imageIds.length] = id;
        imageIds = n;
        images = nImages;
        listeners.fireDataChangeEvent(-1, DataChangedListener.ADDED);
    }

    public long getSelectedImageId() {
        return imageIds[selection];
    }

    public ImageList(long[] images) {
        this.imageIds = images;
        this.images = new EncodedImage[images.length];
    }

    public Image getItemAt(int index) {
        System.out.println("index " + index);
        System.out.println("images[index] " + images[index]);
        if (images[index] == null) {
            images[index] = placeholder;
            Util.downloadUrlToStorageInBackground(galleryPhotoUrlCopy[index], "FullImage_" + imageIds[index], new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    try {
                        images[index] = EncodedImage.create(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("FullImage_" + imageIds[index]));
                        listeners.fireDataChangeEvent(index, DataChangedListener.CHANGED);
                        System.out.println("bibek check in ");
                    } catch (IOException err) {
                        err.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        //            index = 3;
        return images[index];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return imageIds.length;
    }

    public int getSelectedIndex() {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
        WebServiceProxy.getPhotoLikesAsync(imageIds[selection], new Callback<Integer>() {
            public void onSucess(Integer value) {
                if (likeCount != null) {
                }
            }

            public void onError(Object sender, Throwable err, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
            }
        });
        selection = index;
    }

    public void addDataChangedListener(DataChangedListener l) {
        listeners.addListener(l);
    }

    public void removeDataChangedListener(DataChangedListener l) {
        listeners.removeListener(l);
    }

    public void addSelectionListener(SelectionListener l) {
    }

    public void removeSelectionListener(SelectionListener l) {
    }

    public void addItem(Image item) {
    }

    public void removeItem(int index) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoint in the `getSize` method of the model and see the length of the array returned. I'm assuming its 2 which would explain what you are seeing.

If you don't need the image id mechanism just replace it with something else and have the model map to your "real" data structure which is the whole point of having a model.

Comment: one more thing I want to know. You had used downloadUrlTo StorageIn Background. It takes lot of time to download & display in img viewer. I jst want to show the images without downloading images. how can I do that?

Comment: If you don't want to download them just add the image object to the model.

Comment: which method should I use in stead of Util.downloadUrlToStorageInBackground to just add the image object to the model. thankyou

Comment: Those are two unrelated things. You can download the image in any way you want. Adding it to the model is up to your implementation.